# 401 unauthorized error while creating object in back4app via Temboo

Tags: parse-server, back4app, temboo

I am creating an object in parse (using back4app parse server for this).

I get the following error when I run the choreo in temboo.

[image]

> A HTTP Error has occurred: The remote server responded with a status
>   code of 401. Typically this indicates that an authorization error
>   occurred while attempting to access the remote resource. The data
>   returned from the remote server was: {"error":"unauthorized"} . The
>   error occurred in the HTTPSend (Parse) step.

Answer (score 0):

That 401 error might indicate that the Id or Keys are not correct. Maybe it could be a good idea to double check them.

Also, what is the host and path for the API Request that you're doing with Temboo (I'm not acquainted with it)? If you're not using the correct ones it might cause problems too.
Make sure you're reaching something like this:

```
https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Your_Class_Name
```